# Standards for questions

Tags: support, feature-request, status-completed

What exactly are the the standards for asking a question in title and body?

This just came up for me because I wanted to ask a question but had to unnecessarily make my title and body longer because I was shown the ["This post does not meet our quality standards."  message](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/quality-standards-error).

So it would be nice to see **why** the title or body doesn't meet the standard and not let the users guess.

Comment: Have a look at [this Meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92074/208518) for more guidance. The problems seen most often are with poorly worded titles and capitalisation, and question formatting is also taken into account. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Also note that [your question](http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/28056/49) is not unnecessarily long.

Comment: Of course its not long, but the last line is not necessary.

Comment: It is, it provides some context to the users who might want to try to help you. It's important that you give some background, and show some effort in research.

Comment: As for the feature request part, I'll see what can be done about adding a link to the help centre post in the warning.

Comment: We can't tell you why you initial post did not fulfill the quality standards, because we don't know what you posted. There could be a numbers of things wrong with it. Please include your initial post title and body, andvwe can give you an idea of what's wrong with it.

Comment: This question wasn´t aimed at a specific question, you can however find the link and what i wanted to post in the comments above

Answer (score 2):

There's no *standard* per say, but generally questions should be as detailed as you can make them. This is why there are minimum character limits and such. The more detailed the question, the more likely it is that people will be interested enough to answer. One line questions tend to be seen as low effort.

The Title of your question should be a brief summary of the question:

- Why does X happen?
- If X happened, Why is Y still alive?
- What is the first instance of X in an anime?

The Body of your Question should expand on this summary, including any relevant information:

> I am somewhat confused by the fight scene between A & B in episode Q at time XXm:XXs.
>
> Character A says "I must destroy you, for you are evil", to which Character B replies "You cannot destroy me, No anime characters can defeat me".
>
> If this is true, how did Character A destroy Character B?

As you can see, this is fairly short - but it includes all the information needed for an answerer to immediately know what you are talking about. Therefore, the only standard we impose on how you form your questions is **Quality**.

This might seem intimidating to someone who doesn't have English as a first language, but other users will likely edit your spelling mistakes and such if you have put enough effort into your question.

(P.S. The answer is the anime is actually a comic crossover and Character A is actually an american comic character, not an anime character [What a twist!] )

Comment: This neither answered my question nor did it say anything about feature i requested...

Comment: It actually answers your question, as it provides a set of guidelines you should take into consideration when posting a question. If you're looking for a recipe book on what will exactly get you past the filter, you're not gonna get it anywhere.

Comment: I was not asking for the guidelines (they are easily found) but for how the Filter works. If that is classified thats an answer i can accept.

Comment: @Eumel ah, I understand now. I think there is still value in keeping this answer though, and it looks like Jnat has answered the actual question you wanted answered

Comment: @Eumel The Meta post I linked you to on the comment left on the question states "Exact details about the algorithm are not being released by the team." In fact, you should focus on trying to understand what we regard as a good question and aim for that, instead of trying to figure out what is the minimum you can do just to bypass the filter.

Answer (score 1):

The error message now links to [the error message you pointed to in the question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/quality-standards-error), so that users are provided with better guidance.

Specifics about the algorithm are not public, though.